# Use HTML5 File Reader and send it to Leaflet Omnivore

Tags: html, leaflet, filereader, layer

I'm using Leaflet JavaScript and following this tutorial:

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

I'm building a tool for my work. It allows the user to upload a CSV file with lat/long info and plot it on a map via Leaflet Omnivore.

I am able to get the html5 examples to work. But, when do I do with the data it reads in? Leaflet Omnivore requires the local path to the file being uploaded like this:

```
         var testCSV = omnivore.csv('path/to/file.csv').addTo(map).on('error', function(error) {
                                console.log(error);
                            });
```

As far as I know, that's not possible to get for security reasons.

Is there any other way to go about getting file path? Or am I going about this totally wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the case where you do not need to retrieve your file remotely through an AJAX call (e.g. using `omnivore.csv`), but you already have the CSV content as string, you can directly use the [`omnivore.csv.parse`](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore#api) function:

```js
var layer = omnivore.csv.parse(csvStringContent).addTo(map);
// Executed synchronously, so no need to use the .on('ready') listener.
map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/358/

Comment: I wish I could give this more upvotes. Thanks so much!