# Leaflet Omnivore add a layer from text in JS variable instead of KML file

Tags: leaflet

I need to display a map on a web page with hundreds of interactive individual layers. I add each layer to the map using a `.kml` file with JavaScript like this:

```
customLayer1 = L.geoJson(null, {
  style: function(feature) {
    return { color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.99)' };
  }
});

runLayer1 = omnivore.kml('LINK TO KML FILE #1', null, customLayer1);
runLayer1.addTo(map);
```

This will result in hundreds of network requests to load each `.kml` file individually. If there is a way to create a layer using the existing text inside a JavaScript variable (instead of loading it from a Url) I can combine all my `.kml` files into one and fetch it in one request and then `explode` it on the client side to be added as different layers to the map. Can I do that? Or do you suggest any other solution?

Comment: Right in https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore#api : `.kml.parse(kmlString`

Comment: Similarly see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45359618/use-html5-file-reader-and-send-it-to-leaflet-omnivore/45360570?r=SearchResults#45360570